# How to mute and unmute microphone during a capture session in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avplayer, avcapturesession

I'm recoding a video in an iOS app using `AVCaptureSession`.

I want to mute the microphone during parts of the recording. I'm creating an `AVCaptureConnection` from my `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` object.

```
    AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieFileOutput = [AVCaptureMovieFileOutput new];
    if([self.captureSession canAddOutput:movieFileOutput])
    {
        [self.captureSession addOutput:movieFileOutput];
        self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
        
        AVCaptureConnection *connection = [movieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if(connection.isVideoStabilizationSupported)
        {
            connection.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeAuto;
        }
        
        // AVCaptureConnection for audio
        self.audioConnection = [movieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

        self.movieFileOutput = movieFileOutput;
    }
```

I can mute the microphone at the start of the recording with the `enabled` property.

```
self.audioConnection.enabled = NO;
```

However, if I enable this property during the recording, the capture session stops and this delegate method is called.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)output 
didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL 
      fromConnections:(NSArray<AVCaptureConnection *> *)connections 
                error:(NSError *)error;
```

I can start recording a second video clip with audio and then combine the two video clips, but this solution is not ideal and creates a stutter between the two videos.

Is it possible to mute and unmute the microphone during a capture session in iOS?